# how to colored and ouput code in jupyter?

Tags: colors, jupyter-notebook, output

For a presentation I want to show internal code inside packages in Jupyter notebook, I could manage to get the code, but it's plain text (image[1]), Is it exist a way to color the output like image[2]?

here's my code:

```
import inspect

def printSource(obj):
    print(''.join(str(x) for x in inspect.getsourcelines(obj)[0]))

printSource(printSource)
```

I guess should be there a way, because when there's an error, shows colors like image[3]

[image: 1: actual, 2: expected, 3: actual error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coud use %psource, but also you need to tell jupyter where to print, try this

```
from IPython.core import page
page.page = print
```

then, one per cell the function you want to show

```
%psource printSource
```

Answer (score 1):

Prefacing a function with `??` will show its source code with some highlighting (along with some other things). Define a function in a cell like this:

```
def foo():
    print('Hello there: {}'.format(3))
```

And then in another cell:

```
??foo
```

Comment: Thanks @yoskovia, it's so helpful, but still not what I wanted, is there a way to set that code directly bellow the cell?